# I need my code to get the values before the commas but it only grabs one of them - Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I am fairly new to the Javascript language.

I am trying to make a clicker game (not so hard). The game is working but I am trying to make a save method for the game.

Instead of cookies I decided to have the game make its own code where the user can copy and paste it the next time they get on the game.

So the save method works but when I try to have the game load the code it doesn't quite do it right.

**Instead of grabbing the values before the commas it grabs the letters of the word I use as a checker.**

**Is there a way I can fix this?**

Here's my code:

```js
var shovel = 0;
var miner = 0;
var loaders = 0;
var drill = 0;
var tnt = 0;
var minecart = 0;
var bulldozer = 0;
var trucks = 0;
var manager = 0;

var cost1 = 10;
var cost2 = 200;
var cost3 = 350;
var cost4 = 500;
var cost5 = 600;
var cost6 = 800;
var cost7 = 2500;
var cost8 = 6000;
var cost9 = 100000;

var cash = 0;
var cashRate = 1000;


//-- SAVE GAME --
function save() {
 var save = "";
 
 var data = cash + "," + cashRate + "," + shovel + "," + miner + "," + loaders + "," + drill + "," + tnt + "," + minecart + "," + bulldozer + "," + trucks + "," + manager + "," + cost1 + "," + cost2 + "," + cost3 + "," + cost4 + "," + cost5 + "," + cost6 + "," + cost7 + "," + cost8 + "," + cost9;
 
 save += "CoalMinerGame=" + data;
 
 var finalSave = encode(save);//Encoding/Decoding is done using the Base64 Code
 
 prompt("Keep this somewhere you'll remember!", finalSave);
}


function load() {
 
 var code = prompt("Paste the save code below!", "");
 
 if (code != "") {
  var load = decode(code);
  
  if (load.includes("CoalMinerGame=")) {
   load.split("CoalMinerGame=");
   
   //load[0] = blank
   cash = load[1];
   cashRate = load[2];
   shovel = load[3];
   miner = load[4];
   loaders = load[5];
   drill = load[6];
   tnt = load[7];
   minecart = load[8];
   bulldozer = load[9];
   trucks = load[10];
   manager = load[11];
   cost1 = load[12];
   cost2 = load[13];
   cost3 = load[14];
   cost4 = load[15];
   cost5 = load[16];
   cost6 = load[17];
   cost7 = load[18];
   cost8 = load[19];
   cost9 = load[20];
   
   updateWorkers();
   alert("Save Successfully Loaded!");
  } else {
   alert("Not a valid save code!");
  }
 } else {
  alert("You must enter a save code to get your game back!");
 }
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Save Game" onclick="save();">Save</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Load Game" onclick="load();">Load</a>
```

Comment: Tip: any time you use many variables with numbers after their names, you should immediately thing, _"Oh! I should be using an array for this!"_

Comment: Have you ever considered json, the JavaScript Object notation, to store your data?  Why invent your own parsing when you can just use JSON!

Comment: Once working, you may wish to post your code to [codereview](http://codereview.stackoverflow.com); if the final, working result looks anything like the above, there are a great many ways it could be improved, which will improve your JavaScript and HTML skills in general.

Comment: The decode is something you wrote?

Comment: Just do `load = load.split("CoalMinerGame=");` ? Instead of `load.split("CoalMinerGame=");`

Comment: what's the status of this question? there have been answers given but none accepted or comments placed under any of them. So it's unsure if it solved or not.

Answer (score 0):

I see two mistakes :

- The `load.split()` function does not modify `load` but returns an array instead, an array that you should store in another variable.
- You should also split once again the resulting string on commas to separate your different values.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Oh man, this code is giving me a pain :).

What about use some native functions for whole objects so you dont have to manually serialize it and deserialize it?

This code

```
const myObject = {
    some: 'fields',
    even: {
        nested: 'fields',
    },
};

    const stringified = JSON.stringify(myObject);
    console.log(stringified);
    const unstringified = JSON.parse(stringified);
    console.log(unstringified);
```

Is having this output

```
{"some":"fields","even":{"nested":"fields"}}
{ some: 'fields', even: { nested: 'fields' } }
```

You can also use base64 steps to code and decode

---

The JSON.stringify take JS object and create pure string which contains JSON inside.

Then when you want to take JSON and create object from it, you can just JSON.Parse, which expects string.

Answer (score 0):

I echo the sentiment to use JSON. My example below might require some refactoring in the game code but would be cleaner.  To access the variable cash you would just use gameData.cash where you currently are using the cash var.

```
   var gameData = {
    cash: 0,
    cashRate:0,
    shovel:0,
    miner:0,
    loaders:0,
    drill:0,
    tnt:0,
    minecart:0,
    bulldozer:0,
    trucks:0,
    manager:0,
    cost1:10,
    cost2:200,
    cost3:350,
    cost4:500,
    cost5:600,
    cost6:800,
    cost7:2500,
    cost8:6000,
    cost9:100000
}
function save(){
    var dataToSave = CoalMinerGame: {
        cash: cash,
        cashRate:cashRate,
        shovel:shovel,
        miner:miner,
        loaders:loaders,
        drill:drill,
        tnt:tnt,
        minecart:minecart,
        bulldozer:bulldozer,
        trucks:trucks,
        manager:manager,
        cost1:cost1,
        cost2:cost2,
        cost3:cost3,
        cost4:cost4,
        cost5:cost5,
        cost6:cost6,
        cost7:cost7,
        cost8:cost8,
        cost9:cost9
    }

    var finalSave = JSON.Stringify(dataToSave)
    finalSave = encode(finalSave)
    prompt("Keep this somwhere you'll remember!", finalSave)
}

function load(){
    var code = prompt("Paste the save code below!", "")
    var load = decode(code)

    if (code != ""){
        gameData = load;

        updateWorkers();
        alert("Save Successfully loaded!")
    } else {
        alert("You must enter a save code to get your game back!")
    }
}
```